# Cart system timeout for unique items

Tags: timeout, e-commerce, cart

I'm developing a cart system for a uncommon shop and could use some input here.

1. This shop isn't selling commodities or stocked products but rather unique items identified by a id number.
2. There is a great afflux of users wanting to buy a given item after it is listed.
3. Purchases are paid with the balance avaliable on the site which can be rolled back
4. The objective is to avoid :

   - keeping items hidden from the listing while reserved in carts, being unavaliable to other buyers (which exposes a problem when done intentionally).
   - Constant polling of cart contents and expiration times
   - Removing items from the cart automatically, causing confusion on users
   - Bugs causing the same item to be purchased more than once

How would you approach this? allow concurrent reservations? Persist items and charge upon reservation and take fee on cancellation? etc...

I'm really interested in knowing about your outlook on this.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Ticketmaster has a similar problem... they allow you to place (sometimes highly coveted) seat reservations in your cart.

They approach this by

1. Clearly communicating the period of time that the seat will remain in your cart once you reserve it
2. Showing a countdown next to the item in the shopping cart with a prominent font and color.

On the back end, I expect that they maintain a list of reserved seats and when they will expire.  Once an item expires from that master list, the item in the cart is returned to general inventory.  I expect that it may still stay in the cart in an unreserved state (after all, if nobody ELSE wanted the seats even though the reservation expired, why make it hard for the buyer to get them).